# Llamar a un método al cambiar de componente - Angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript, router

Buenos días,
mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Tengo un componente llamado "CreateSystem", con el cual realizo una llamada al pulsar un botón:

```
<button (click)="onCreateSystem()" type="button">Create</button>
```

El método llamado es el siguiente:

```
onCreateSystem(){
        this.router.navigate(['/systems']);
    }
```

El objetivo es abrir otra URL de mi página web que contine otro componente. Hasta ahí todo funciona, la llamada se realiza correctamente.

El problema es que me gustaría llamar un método GET a un servicio REST tras este, y no tengo muy claro como realizarlo. Creía que con usarlo en onInit sería suficiente, pero parece ser que no se ejecuta.

```
 export class SystemsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private baseService: BaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSystems();
  }
```

El método GET funciona, mi problema es que no soy capaz de ejecutarlo tras `this.router.navigate(['/systems']);`

He comprobado el cilco de vida:
[Ciclo de vida](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)  de las viws, pero no tengo claro cual usar
¿Alguna sugerencia?
Saludos

Comment: Qué devuelve `this.getSystems()`? Si es un Observable, es normal que esa línea de código no haga nada

Comment: Perdonad, estaba ocupado durante el fin de semana. Se trata de un observable. Lo que quiero es que se llame a dicho método cuando actualizo y cambio a dicha URL. El método es llamado cuando realizo el init, pero no cuando inicio el componente mediante this.router.navigate(['/systems']); "desde otro componente"

Answer (score 1):

Cuando navegas pasa un parametro "x" y desde tu componente **SystemsComponent** te subscribes asi capturas tu metodo http.get()

metodo:

```
onCreateSystem(){
  let x: boolean = true
  this.router.navigate(['/systems'], { queryParams: { x: x } });
```

}

**systems.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";  
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router/";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-systems',
  templateUrl: './systems.component.html'
})

export class SystemsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges  {

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe((params: any) => {
        let json: string = JSON.stringify(params)
        params == true?this.getSystems():"";
    });
  }

  getSystems() {
    this.http.get("http://ws.geeklab.com.ar/dolar/get-dolar-json.php")
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(miobj => {
        console.log(miobj)
    });
  }

}
```

> Esa api obtiene el dolar a la fecha actual

---

---

Lo ideal es que hagas uso de un servicio para consumir el metodo http.get()

**systems.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()

export class NotificacionesService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getSystems(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("http://ws.geeklab.com.ar/dolar/get-dolar-json.php")
  }

}
```

Y luego desde tu componente consumes el servicio.

Comment: Ahora mismo lo pruebo! Muchas gracias por la elaborada respuesta. En cuanto confirme, doy el voto de aprobación